# Android Using Image as Background of ListView?

Tags: android, image, layout, background

Rather then setting list view to to particular background color I would like to fill the background with an image?  How can this be done?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any view's background can be a colour or an image or an XML-based drawable.

Put your image in your res/drawable folder, and in your layout XML set your `ListView` to have an `android:background="@drawable/myimage"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks I there a way to make the list items background transparent so that you have the background of the listview as the background of each item?

Comment: They will be transparent by default, unless you're on 1.x IIRC. You will probably also want to set android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" on the listview.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   Place the image in drawable folder which is under res folder  and
> ```
>
> set it as background to List view as
>   Shown i below

```
     <ListView android:id="@+id/mymovies" android:cacheColorHint="#cccccc" 
               android:layout_weight="1" android:scrollbars="vertical" 
              android:smoothScrollbar="true"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:background="@drawable/imagename">
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the list item views transparent so that you see only the background of the whole list?

Answer (score 1):

I confused with your question. Where you exactly want to set the backgroud image ? in listview or background at list item?

If you want to set background in listview items then you have to create a **`Custom listview`** . Here you found an example to accomplish this: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example-part-2/

Comment: Actually What I want exactly is to have a transparent background to the whole list view.  And the list view items will have a transparent background. So when you look at a list item you will see the background of the list as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setBackgroundDrawable` or `setBackgroundResource`.

Comment: WHat is the difference between the two in terms of efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you want to add a background image to any kind of inflated list ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter, then - Make sure that the background image is defined in the parent layout, or parent view, for example the main layout, using the attribute "*android:background="@drawable/backupimage*". 
*Do not* set the background in the XML representing the custom-row/object-view of the repeating instances.

This way the background image will be displayed only once, appearing static behind all inflated objects, and not duplicated again and again on every single row/object.